# имеет ли право на жизнь такая реализация календаря?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

```js
let elem3 = document.querySelector('body')

//create empty table in tag with rows and cols
function createTable(tag, rows, cols) {
  let table = document.createElement('table')
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr')
    for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      let td = document.createElement('td')
      tr.append(td)
    }
    table.append(tr)
  }
  tag.append(table)
  return table
}

function createCalendar(tag, year = new Date().getFullYear(), month = new Date().getMonth()) {
  const weekDays = ['Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб', 'Вс'];
  let table = createTable(tag, 7, 7)
  let date = new Date(year, month - 1)
  let arr = table.querySelectorAll('td')
  //set names of weekdays
  Array.from(table.firstChild.children).forEach((elem, i) => elem.innerText = weekDays[i])
  //get days in current month
  let dayInMonth = 32 - new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 32).getDate()
  //get current col in table to insert days
  let col = date.getDay() - 1 && date.getDay() - 1 + 7
  //insert days
  for (let i = 1; i <= dayInMonth; i++) {
    arr[7 + col].innerText = i
    col++
  }
}

createCalendar(elem3, 2020, 3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Имеет ли право на жизнь такая реализация календаря?

Ответ: Да!)

Бросились в глаза две детали:

`let dayInMonth = 32 - new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 32).getDate()`

day - что за день? Можно было вникать в код, но лень подсказала - сначала вывести значение в консоль. После чего захотелось переименовать его в `daysInMonth` (а возможно, еще завернуть его значение в функцию, и потерять её где-то внизу: Потому что это специфичная фишка Date, которую не обязательно знать)

`let col = date.getDay() - 1 && date.getDay() - 1 + 7` — Если бывают такие выражения, полезно использовать скобки, потому что сходу можно и не вспомнить приоритеты всех операций. Полез в [справочник](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) и фактически, оно работает так: `( date.getDay() - 1 ) && ( date.getDay() - 1 + 7 )` во-вторых, не совсем правильно:

```js
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].forEach(n => {
  console.log( n, n - 1 && n - 1 + 7 );
});
```

Если есть какой-то набор чисел и из него нужно получить другие числа, полезно их сперва сопоставить, чтобы вообще понять, чего хотим... .getDay() возвращает числа от 0 (вскр) до 6 (субб), и из этого нужно получить 6, 0, 1, ...5 (индекс td):

```
> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
> 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

А это `(n + 6) % 7`

---

Ну и, как вариант переоформления:

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('body');

createCalendar(elem, 2020, 3);

/***/
function createCalendar(elem, year, month) {
  year = year || new Date().getFullYear();
  month = month || new Date().getMonth();
  // Если значений по умолчанию много или они слишком длинные.

  let table = createTable(elem, 7, 7);

  fillDayNames();
  fillDays();

  /***/
  function fillDayNames() {
    let names = ['Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб', 'Вс'];
    let td = table.querySelectorAll("tr:nth-child(1) td");

    names.forEach((name, i) => td[i].textContent = name);
  }

  function fillDays() {
    let date = new Date(year, month - 1);
    let startFromCol = (date.getDay() + 6) % 7;
    let daysInMonth = 32 - new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 32).getDate();
    
    let td = [...table.querySelectorAll("td")].slice(7);
    for (let i = 0; i < daysInMonth; i++) {
      td[startFromCol + i].textContent = i + 1;
    }
  }
}

function createTable(elem, rows, cols) {
  let tds = "<td></td>".repeat(cols);
  let trs = ("<tr>" + tds + "</tr>").repeat(rows);
  elem.innerHTML = "<table>" + trs + "</table>";

  return elem.firstChild;
}
```

Хотя, было бы лучше изначально как-то разделить названия дней и числа (например, классом), чтобы потом и стили легче писались.

Comment: Про скобки прям совершенно не согласен.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME спасибо за ответ,разъяснения и свои внесения изменений в код

Comment: @Qwertiy♦ О_о Именно в этом случае, или в принципе - нужно запоминать приоритеты всех операторов?)

Comment: @Qwertiy запоминать не нужно)) но скобки лишними не будут) он прав

Comment: Приоритеты операторов надо знать и использовать. // cc @Armen

Comment: @Qwertiy  приоритеты всех операторов?)

Comment: @Armen, а чем не устраивает?

Comment: @Qwertiy есть ключевые операторы && || итд и есть операторы скажем битовые которые если использовать то ооочень редко ну так смысл запоминать все ? в случае чего можно глянуть

Comment: @Armen, вот встретишь в коде `x = Math.ramdom() * 100 | 0` или `x[key] = ~~x[key] + 1` - и что делать будешь?

Comment: @Qwertiy гляну в справочник если на ходу не разберусь будет такое встречатся часто тогда афтоматом запомню

Comment: @Qwertiy просто надо знать что что то такое есть но запоминать их приоритеты это перебор как по мне если их не использовать

Comment: @Armen, так использовать тоже надо)

Answer (score 1):

На первый взгляд, что захотелось изменить:

- циклически создается таблица, затем циклически заполняется, после надо будет повесить стили и вновь придется циклически прогонять таблицу. Здесь хочется испольозвать один цикл, который будет добавлять DOM элементы, заполнять данными и весить стили в одной итерации. Дело не в ресурсах, а целостности задачи;
- в основной функции три разных этапа: подготовили дни недели в массив - отправили на экран через `forEach`, затем рассчитали отступ - запомнили уже в обычной переменной, после уже через `for` выводим дни... смотрелось немного разрозненно. Захотелось чтоб это была подготовка идинообразных данных, сумму которых можно было бы отправить в таблицу, например, массив. И разделить функционал - одна функция готовит данные, другая занимается выводом.

Примерно такая цель была перед началом работы. Дальше пошло-поехало и подумал "пусть это будет не таблица, а флексы?"(для таблицы `div` надо просто поменять на `table`, `tr` и `td` и скорректирвоать стили).
В общем, это варинт который вырос на основе вашего и получил чуть больше функционала. Покажется что-то полезным или нет - решать вам.

```js
const namesOfWeekDays = ['Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб', 'Вс'];
const calendar = {
  table: 'calendar',
  row: 'calendar__row',
  cell: 'calendar__cell',
  untouchable: 'calendar__cell--untouchable',
  sundayMod: 'calendar__cell--sunday',
}
const emptyCell = ' ';
const outMonthDay = 33;
const daysOfWeek = 7;
const body = document.body;

function renderTable(tag, cellsList) {
  const table = document.createElement('div');
  table.className = calendar.table;
  let rowPosition;
  
  cellsList.forEach((element, index) => {
    const isMonday = index % daysOfWeek === 0;
    const isSunday = (index + 1) % daysOfWeek === 0;
    const isUntouchable = index < daysOfWeek || element === emptyCell;
    
    if (isMonday) {
      rowPosition = document.createElement('div');
      rowPosition.className = calendar.row;
      table.append(rowPosition);
    }
    
    const cell = document.createElement('div');
    cell.innerText = element;
    cell.className = isSunday ? `${calendar.cell} ${calendar.sundayMod}` : calendar.cell;
    if (isUntouchable) {
      cell.classList.add(calendar.untouchable);
    }
    rowPosition.append(cell);
  })
  tag.append(table);
}

function createCalendar(tag, year = new Date().getFullYear(), month = new Date().getMonth()) {
  const date = new Date(year, month, 1);
  const lengthOfMonth = outMonthDay - new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), outMonthDay).getDate();
  const firstDayOfMonth = date.getDay();
  const lengthEmptyCellsBefor = firstDayOfMonth === 0 ? 6 : firstDayOfMonth - 1;
  const lengthEmptyCellsAfter = daysOfWeek - (lengthOfMonth + lengthEmptyCellsBefor) % daysOfWeek;
  
  const emptyCellsBefor = Array(lengthEmptyCellsBefor).fill(emptyCell)
  const daysOfMonth = Array(lengthOfMonth).fill().map((el, index) => index + 1);
  const emptyCellsAfter = Array(lengthEmptyCellsAfter).fill(emptyCell)
  renderTable(tag, [...namesOfWeekDays, ...emptyCellsBefor, ...daysOfMonth, ...emptyCellsAfter]);
}

createCalendar(body, 2020, 2);
```

```css
.calendar {
  --color-bg-cell: #3333;
  --color-sunday: red;
  
  max-width: 220px;
}

.calendar__row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.calendar__cell {
  text-align: center;
  width: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.calendar__cell:hover {
  background-color: var(--color-bg-cell);
}

.calendar__cell--sunday {
  color: var(--color-sunday);
}

.calendar__cell--untouchable {
  cursor: default;
}

.calendar__cell--untouchable:hover {
  background: none;
}
```

Comment: кода как-то заметно больше стало

Comment: "собачка в пути могла подрасти") Больше стало на операциях со стилями и вынесенных константах.

Comment: @ИльяЛокалин любой альтернативный подход полезен поскольку можно что то новое узнать спасибо